# NativeScrip + Angular 2 - http 'getCookie' of null

Tags: angular, nativescript

When I use `http.get` this is what I got. I try all solutions that I find here and none is working.

My code is from:
http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-4

> JS: EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null
>   JS: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null
>   JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null
>   JS:     at CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:1183:91)
>   JS:     at XHRBackend.createConnection (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:1223:32)
>   JS:     at httpRequest (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:1561:24)
>   JS:     at Http.request (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:1661:38)
>   JS:     at Http.get (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:1672:25)
>   JS:     at AppService.load (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/app.service.js:13:26)
>   JS:     at AppComponent.ngOnInit (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/app.component.js:11:25)
>   JS:     at Wrapper_AppComponent.detectChangesInInputProps (/AppComponentModule/AppComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:18:53)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppComponentModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:36:26)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.apka4/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)

Comment: Could you give more info about your case or to provide some code, where you made your HTTP request. In the mean time you could review the sample example here, where has been used NativeScript HttpModule - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/httpModule/http-module-get

Answer (score 1):

Can you please make sure you are importing the `NativeScriptHttpModule` in your main app module. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/master/app/app.module.ts#L23).

It defines a provider for the `Http` which is the original `Http` service form `@angular/http`, but wrapped so that it can execute inside NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

On your **main.ts** file you must import **NativeScriptHttpModule** see this:

```
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http"; // import
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...appComponents,
],
bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule // add NativeScript Http module here
],
providers: [
    // your providers here
]})
```